# Failed installing luarocks in windows 8.1

Tags: lua

I want to install Luarocks on my pc windows 8.1.

I run command prompt as administrator without success !
I receive this message :

[image]

Any advice ?

Comment: Do what the error message tells you to do? `run with admin privileges or use the /noadmin switch`.

Comment: I post an image

Comment: Done without success !

Comment: I use /NOADMIN option Luarocks failed

Comment: As you can see administrateur (french)

Comment: https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/Installation-instructions-for-Windows